# SQLite: INSERT or REPLACE w/ null PRIMARY KEY

Tags: python, replace, sqlite, duplicates

I am trying to `INSERT or REPLACE INTO t1` if the `name` is already there. I understand if the id is set then replace will work, but I need it to react to name.

```
import sqlite3

def insert(name):
    cur.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO t1(name) VALUES(?)', [name])    

def select():
    return cur.execute('SELECT * FROM t1').fetchall()


conn = sqlite3.connect('test')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1(
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                name TEXT NOT NULL
                )''') 


insert('jack')
insert('jack')
insert('jack')

print select()
```

output

```
[(1, u'jack'), (2, u'jack'), (3, u'jack')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT or REPLACE ...` will do replace only if there are collisions. And as your `name` column isnt collidable, this event cannot accur (at least not on `name`). You need to make `name` collidable:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS iname ON t1 (name)
```

Also note that you dont need to have `id` column, because sqlite3 has `ROWID` on every table.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the explanation. `ROWID` is going to be a big help to.